# IIS Rewrite Rule for adding versioning to the url if not found

Tags: iis

How can convert url [www.mydomain.com/home](http://www.mydomain.com/home) to [www.mydomain.com/api/v1/home](http://www.mydomain.com/api/v1/home)

if the requested api link don't contain api/v1

I need someone help to write iis rewrite rule in web.config to fit this case

best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "if not found"? Besides, it is good manner to ask for hints/tips and then do it yourself, instead of "need someone help to write".

Answer (score -1):

> if the requested api link don't contain api/v1

You can use the parameter `^home$` to make the requested url match only home, this way api/v1 is not contained.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^home$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domainname.com$" />
          </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainname.com/api/v1/home" appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Body cannot contain mydomain, so i use domainname instead of it.